# Osx chrome use ctrl key based shortcuts instead of command key based

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I was a windows user and now work on a macbook, I use chrome as my default web browser, in an osx chrome, all shortcuts are designed as command based, such as command + T to open a new tab. I want to use CTRL-based shortcuts that use CTRL + T to open a new tab instead. I just want this in chrome instead of a global key remap. Is anyway to do it？ Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: Potentially, for some non-global commands, but honestly, you will be far better off in the long run to learn the new paradigm rather than fight it. Max 2 months & you'll never look back. You will also hit potential conflicts whilst using the browser, for instance on this site, where ctrl/q is 'quote'... not 'quit'

Answer (score 2):

- **Step 1:** Open "System Preferences"
- **Step 2:** Select "Keyboard"
- **Step 3:** Select "Shortcuts"
- **Step 4:** Select "App Shortcuts" (it's on the left side)
- **Step 5:** Click the "+" sign at the bottom the white window like space (it's on the right side)
- **Step 6:** Select Application: "Google Chrome.app" from the dropdown menu. Enter "New Tab" in the "Menu Title" field. Enter ctrl+T in the "Keyboard Shortcut" field. Click Add.

**Note:** Please, make sure ctrl+T is NOT conflicting with another existing keyboard shortcut.
[Here is a screenshot that might be useful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDZnX.png)

Comment: Not sure "App Shortcuts" is still available?

Comment: If I wanted to use Control instead of Command for all keyboard shortcuts, must they all be added individually in this manner?

Comment: Worth also doing "Close Tab" for control+W